# "R: Calculating robust normals for a LiDAR point cloud and tracking valid indices"

Tags: r, point-clouds, eigenvector, normals, lidar

I am working with LiDAR point cloud data in R and trying to calculate the robust normals for the points using a local plane-based approach. My goal is to compute the normals for each point in the point cloud and keep track of the valid indices where the normals have been successfully computed.

I have written a function called robust_normals to perform this task, which uses the RANN package to find neighbors within a search radius around each point. Then, it calculates the normal vectors using eigen decomposition on the covariance matrix of the centered neighbor points.

The problem is that when I run this function, it does not return the correct list of valid indices where the normals have been computed. Here's the current implementation of my robust_normals function:

```
robust_normals <- function(pts, search_radius = 10) {
  kdtree <- RANN::nn2(pts, query = pts, treetype = "kd", searchtype = "radius", radius = search_radius)
  normals <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(pts), ncol = 3)
  valid_indices <- list()
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(pts)) {
    neighbors <- pts[kdtree$nn.idx[[i]], , drop = FALSE]
    
    if (nrow(neighbors) < 2) {
      cat("Not enough neighbors for point", i, "\n")
      next
    }
    
    centered_neighbors <- scale(neighbors, scale = FALSE, center = pts[i, ])
    cov_matrix <- cov(centered_neighbors)
    
    if (any(is.infinite(cov_matrix)) || any(is.na(cov_matrix))) {
      cat("Invalid covariance matrix for point", i, "\n")
      next
    }
    
    eigen_decomp <- eigen(cov_matrix)
    normals[i, ] <- eigen_decomp$vectors[, 3]
    valid_indices[[length(valid_indices) + 1]] <- i
  }
  
  return(list(normals = normals, valid_indices = valid_indices))
}
```

The valid_indices list turns out to be empty (NULL), even though there should be valid indices where normals have been successfully computed. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone help me identify the issue with my implementation or suggest an alternative way to compute the robust normals and keep track of the valid indices?

Comment: What is the meaning of "normals" in this context. In geometry the term normal has a meaning quite different than in statistics. Do you mean "expected"? And if so do you want some localized version of a mean or expected value?

Comment: In this context, the term "normals" does not refer to a statistical concept but rather to a geometric one. Specifically, it refers to the normal vectors of local planes fitted to the neighborhood of each point in a LiDAR point cloud.

A normal vector is a vector that is perpendicular to a plane, and it can be used to represent the orientation of that plane. In the context of LiDAR point clouds, normals are used to describe the local geometry of the point cloud around each point, which can be helpful for differentiating between different types of surfaces

Comment: There’s no way we can help debug this unless we have a complete example. Add needed ‘library’ calls and a sample dataset. Sometimes adding an example from a help page will suffice.